# I can not view data from a query in a webservice

Tags: c#, web-services, sql-server-2008

I have a problem, need to display the contents of a query in the database with webservice, serializing with Json.

My Billing List

```
using BiDAL.Entity.Graficos;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace BiDAL.Persistence
{
    public class FaturamentoIvelDAL : Conexao
    {
        public List<FaturamentoIvel> FindAllFaturamentoIvel()
        {
            try
            {
                OpenConnection();
                Cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT Operacao, AnoMes, TradeMarketing, SUM(ValorNF) AS ValorTotal FROM dbo.FatoFaturamentoIVEL WHERE TradeMarketing = 0 GROUP BY Operacao, AnoMes, TradeMarketing ORDER BY SUM(ValorNF) DESC", Con);

                Dr = Cmd.ExecuteReader();
                List<FaturamentoIvel> lista = new List<FaturamentoIvel>();

                while (Dr.Read())
                {
                    FaturamentoIvel ft = new FaturamentoIvel();
                    ft.Operacao = Convert.ToString(Dr["Operacao"]);
                    ft.AnoMes = Convert.ToString(Dr["AnoMes"]);
                    ft.ValorNF = Convert.ToSingle(Dr["ValorNF"]);

                    lista.Add(ft);
                }
                return lista;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw new Exception("Erro ao listar Faturamento: " + ex.Message);
            }
        } 
    }
}
```

My WebService

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Script.Services;
using System.Web.Services;
using BiDAL.Persistence;
using BiDAL.Entity;
using BiDAL.Util;
using BiFrontEnd.Controllers;


namespace BiFrontEnd 
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Summary description for WebService
    /// </summary>
    [WebService(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]
    [WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
    [System.ComponentModel.ToolboxItem(false)]
    // To allow this Web Service to be called from script, using ASP.NET AJAX, uncomment the following line. 
    // [System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]
    public class WebService : System.Web.Services.WebService
    {

        [WebMethod]
        [ScriptMethod(UseHttpGet= true, ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
        public void GerarGraficoFaturamentoIvel(Conexao Con)
        {
            try
            {
                Context.Response.Clear();
                Context.Response.ContentType = "application/json";
                Con.OpenConnection();

                Context.Response.Write(Serializer.Serializador(FindAllFaturamentoIvel));
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                throw;
            }
        }

    }
}
```

In the code line "Context.Response.Write(Serializer.Serializador(FindAllFaturamentoIvel));" is giving error in FindAllFaturamentoIvel

Comment: It helps to actually show the error message, but I assume it contains something about the inability to convert a method group? I think you want to call `FindAllFaturamentoIvel()` not serialize the method itself.

Comment: "The name 'FindAllFaturamentoIvel' does not exist in the current context"

Comment: I made a change in post